# FileNotFoundError while debugging in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, spyder

I am running a code in Spyder, which starts with the following line:

```
  f = open("../../../sbd-preprocess-master/data_proc/train.txt", 'r')
```

The statement executes fine if I just run the code in a regular way.
However, if I debug the file, I get a FileNotFoundError at the same line:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../../sbd-preprocess-master/data_proc/train.txt'
```

Any idea why that is happening?